# Codeigniter error log

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I have set error level to `1` in `config.php`.
But the problem is that i am getting many errors that is `NOT ACTUALLY ERRORS in terms of application logic`.

Consider the following code examples

```
  $deleted = @unlink($filename);

  $imap_uid = @imap_uid($con,$msgno);
```

As you can see that the above example will not throw errors, but codeigniter will log if an error occurred.

Is it possible to disable error logging dynamically ?

i am expecting something like this

```
 // ....

   $this->error_log = 0; // disable error logging

   //Perform some operation that which may log an error,even its suppressed 

   $this->error_log = 1; //enable it again

 // ...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend CI_Log class adding setters for $_enabled

```
Class MY_Log extends CI_Log
{
    function enable_logging($item=TRUE) {
         $this->_enabled = (bool)$item;
    }
}
```

Now you can do like this

$this->log->enable_logging(FALSE);//Disable

$this->log->enable_logging();//Enable

Answer (score 0):

Thanks based on Michail's answer i have this more flexible solution using the protected $_threshold variable.

```
Class MY_Log extends CI_Log
{
  public function setThreshold($l){
    if(!in_array($l,array(0,1,2,3,4,5))){
      log_message("error","MY_Log->setThreshold unsupported val: " . $l );
      return false;
    }
    $this->_threshold = $l;
    return true;
  }
}
```

And from your controller you do

```
$this->log->setThreshold(0);
```